# Simultaneous upload files using flow.js and angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-flow

i'm using flow.js for uploading files. Can i upload files simultaneously? Because it seems, that only chunks can be uploaded simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload files simultaneously. Lets say, you select multiple files from browser dialog then ng-flow first break up each of the selected files into chucks.
Then ng-flow sends each chunks, one after the other to the server until all the chunks associated with selected files are uploaded.

Note that once it sends a chuck, it **does not** wait until it get a response from server whether chuck upload is success or not. It immediately starts to upload next chuck.